# angularjs e2e testing assertions with mock http

Tags: angularjs, integration-testing

I currently run my angularjs testing environment using ngMockEE which, using a special testing module allows me to mock http responses as such;

```
var things = [thing01, thing02];

$httpBackend.whenGET('/v1/things?').respond(function() {return [200, things]});
```

In a separate file I define e2e tests which call a things.html file that includes that testing module.

I then define a e2e test like this;

```
browser().navigateTo('/test/thingTest.html');
expect(element('.table.things tbody tr').count()).toEqual(2);
```

Now, what would be nice is if I could somehow couple the two togther, so that I could write an assertion like this - avoiding hard coding that **2** which will need updating over time if I update my list of `things`

```
browser().navigateTo('/test/thingTest.html');
expect(element('.table.things tbody tr').count()).toEqual(things.length);
```

However I'm not quite sure if this is possible or advisable. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use an e2eData.js file containing those values, and which would be loaded both by your tests, and by the tested page:

In e2eData.js:

```
...
var e2eData = {
    things : [thing01, thing02],
    ...
}
```

In your e2e module:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('/v1/things?').respond(function() {return [200, e2eData.things]});
```

In your test:

```
expect(element('.table.things tbody tr').count()).toEqual(e2eData.things.length);
```

Comment: I guess I was trying to avoid using the window scope, but yes that is one approach.